# Unity Face Tracking slow in android

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine

i build the app on unity to track the face but it is very slow. please help me to optimize the code.
I DEVELOP THE APP WITH THE HELP OF THIS VIDEO ON YOUTUBE.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXVHl8Z3ro8

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7zRB62SxqZ-dE1wYVluNkhmT3c/view?usp=sharing    APK that i built.

Comment: Seems code optimization is more fit to Code review  ( http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ) than SO ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ) . And don't caps here please.